# Did Android 14 change how Camera-Cutouts / Menu-Bars got handled? My App has a Black Bar at the top :(

Tags: java, android, mobile

On older API levels, setting these lines in the manifest is enough to get an app fullscreen without black bars at the side, like on phones with camera cutout:

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

In Android 14, I get big black bar at the top of my app on some devices. Even if setting fullscreen window flag and anything else I could think of.

Anyone here experiencing the same issue?

Insetscontroller doesnt seem to change anything either:

```
   insetsController.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
        insetsController.hide(WindowInsets.Type.captionBar());
        insetsController.hide(WindowInsets.Type.displayCutout());
        insetsController.hide(WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars());
        insetsController.hide(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars());
```

And this also doesnt do the trick:

```
  WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;
    lp.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    lp.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    lp.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    int flag =  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;


    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flag);
```

How can I get rid of the black bar at the top of my app that moves everything further downscreen? Logging screensize works but only using realwidth:

```
  WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics realMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getRealMetrics(realMetrics);

        // Fetching the real screen dimensions
        int realWidth = realMetrics.widthPixels;
```